# (mpic++)MPI_Scatter producing wrong results (logical error)

Tags: c++, vector, struct, mpi

I want to scatter a number of elements in a vector of type struct over a number of processes with this minimal code

```
struct node
{
    scale2 P;
    scale2 V;
    float   M;
    //
   node(float M, float Px, float Py) // constructor
    :P(Px,Py)
    , V( 0.f, 0.f )
    , M(m)
   {}
};
```

main function

```
    int main(int argc, char **argv){
        std::vector<node> bodies;
        std::vector<node> b;
        int rank, size, ROOT =0;
        long int pC;


        MPI_Datatype MPI_NODE; 

        MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

        //creating data type that represents node
        //setup description of scale2 and float
        // define and commit structure type

        if(rank == ROOT){
           // initialise bodies
           pC = bodies.size();
           cout <<pC << " nodes" << endl;
        }
        MPI_Bcast(&pC, 1, MPI_LONG, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

        MPI_Scatter(&bodies, pC/size, MPI_NODE, &b, pC/size, MPI_NODE, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        cout << "rank "<<rank<<" has " <<b.size()<<" values of bodies"<<endl;

        //other stuff
        MPI_Finalize();
        return 0;
    }
```

the output I am looking for ( with 4 processes and size of bodies = 64) is

```
rank 0 has 16 values of bodies
rank 1 has 16 values of bodies
rank 2 has 16 values of bodies
rank 3 has 16 values of bodies
```

the output I am getting

```
rank 0 has 64 values of bodies
rank 2 has 2818 values of bodies
rank 1 has 0 values of bodies
rank 3 has 11311978710794943764 values of bodies
```

I am sure the problem is in either the `MPI_Scatter` line or the line below it i.e. the way `b.size()` is being outputted in a wrong way. I issue might also be in the way `vector<node> b` is passed in `MPI_scatter` The rest of the code works fine since I tested without these 2 lines. If this part of the code is not the problem (which I doubt it) then the way I am defining the data type `MPI_NODE` is wrong in which case I will edit my code to show that part as well.

Answer (score 0):

With C++, you cannot simply take the address of a `std::vector`, you must use `.data()`. You also must reserve enough space in the `recvbuf`, which means you must manually `b.resize(pC)`.

There may be more issues in your code, please learn to write a [proper example code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (not just minimal, also complete and verifiable!).

Comment: pC is being broadcasted to every rank doesn't that "initialises" it to every rank?

Comment: and also you are saying that i should try `b.resize(pC/size)` instead of `&b` in `MPI_scatter()`

Comment: Ooops, I overlooked the broadcast - yes that part is fine then. You must `b.resize(pC/sisze);` and then `MPI_Scatter(.... b.data() ...);`

Comment: i just added `b.resize(pC/size)` between the `MPI_Bcast and `MPI_scatter` in my code. then changed the `MPI_Scatter` to `MPI_scatter(&bodies, pC/size,MPI_NODE, b.data(),pC/size,MPI_NODE,ROOT,MPI_COMM_WORLD).
now an error occured stating "no matching function call to node::node()"

Comment: the error Is due to `b.resize()` since b is of type node i cannot just write `b.resize(pC/size)`. i think i have to include node somewhere. i am saying this because in another vector function `push_back` it works in this way.( this is jurt an example) `b.push_back(node(m,px,py))`. something on those lines . i might be wrong

Comment: Yes, you need some default initialization for `node`. If you don't want a default constructor, you can also add a prototypical value as second argument to `std::vector::resize`. Note that you also must use `bodies.data()`!

Comment: i just added an empty constructor in the struct. it worked well thanks!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `b.resize(pC)`? In the end, it's gathering `pC/size` elements from `size` ranks.

Comment: @HristoIliev you are absolutely correct. Certainly not my day.